# Using Apple Developer as proof of sales between two companies

Tags: ios-appstore, accounts, developer-program

We are currently negotiating with a company where that company will use our technology (image recognition) to create an iOS app. We will receive a Royalty based on sales and we do not know the company enough to feel that we can trust them. Neither me nor my co-workers at our start-up are Apple developers.

We want to specify in our licensing-agreement that they should show us their sales via documents from their Apple Developer account. What are the possibilities / do you have any input on what kinds of documents we should specify?

I give the three ideas I am thinking of so far:

1. Include us as receivers in apple-emails if they are generated on a monthly basis on sales.
2. Send us PDF from sales-reports from Apple.
3. Give us special login-password once a month to check.

Is there any better that I am not aware of?

All the best
Duran

Comment: what is it they are proposing as monitoring and reporting? How long is the agreement duration? What happens if you pull the plug on them ?

Comment: I do not really understand the first question. They will summarize everything in a spread-sheet besides the solution via Apple Developer reports. This will be the only monitoring and therefore I want to find something good. The agreement is 5 years. I can't pull the plug. It's a licensing an they have the right to use out technology for the app during the licensing.

Answer (score 1):

The app developing company will publish on the App Store under an App Developer license from Apple. You can ask them to create an iTunes Connect account for your company under **Sales** role. Using it you get access to Sales, Trends and App Analytics.

For further details you can refer to the Apple Developer support documents, [iTunes Connect Resources and Help](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Users%20and%20Roles_Overview) and [User Roles - iTunes Connect](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev82a173c41).